# Node.js + Chai/Mocha/Should: running multiple tests against the same response

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai, should.js

I'm using something very similar to the following to execute a series of API tests using Mocha. This is great, but it requires making a separate API call for each test. **I want to use the same API call and run multiple tests against that response.** I've been reading that you can use `before` to do it, but none of the examples around the web actually show it working with API calls?

```
var chai = require('chai');
var request = require('request');
var async = require('async');
var assert = chai.assert,
    expect = chai.expect,
    should = chai.should();

describe('/', function () {
  it('should return 200', function (done) {
    request.get('http://localhost:8000', function (err, res, body) {
      res.should.have.status(200);
      done();
    });
  });

  it('should say "Hello, world!"', function (done) {
    request.get('http://localhost:8000', function (err, res, body) {
      body.should.have.property('type', 'aType');
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this with a `before` function like so...

```
var chai = require('chai');
var request = require('request');
var async = require('async');
var assert = chai.assert,
    expect = chai.expect,
    should = chai.should();

describe('/', function () {
  var firstRequest;

  before(function(done) {
    request.get('http://localhost:8000', function(err, res, body) {
      firstRequest = {
        err:err,
        res:res,
        body:body
      };
      done();
    });
  });

  it('should return 200', function (done) {
    firstRequest.res.should.have.status(200);
    done();
  });

  it('should say "Hello, world!"', function (done) {
    firstRequest.body.should.have.property('type','aType');
    done();
  });
});
```

However, unless you have a really good reason to do this, I think you're better off just combining the tests.

```
var chai = require('chai');
var request = require('request');
var async = require('async');
var assert = chai.assert,
    expect = chai.expect,
    should = chai.should();

describe('/', function () {
  it('should return 200 and say "Hello, world!"', function (done) {
    request.get('http://localhost:8000', function (err, res, body) {
      res.should.have.status(200);
      body.should.have.property('type', 'aType');
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

If the test fails Mocha will report the specific reason why it failed even though there are two assertions.

Comment: Thought about doing that, but when I have 10 or so body assertions, then it gets really ugly trying to describe what's going on. Was hoping to have a nice clean list of tests in a row with the applicable descriptions.

Comment: Oddly `should.have.status` doesn't seem to play nicely doing it this way - not sure why. Hopefully I figure it out lol!

Comment: Just one update: you don't need `done` on the tests if you are just checking the response. There is nothing async going on inside the `it()` clauses in your first example.

Comment: Also, I tend to separate them (your first style), since it makes it easier to isolate problems, e.g. if one part fails, it is a separate `it(should)` and thus easier to isolated with an `it.only()` and debug

Comment: @deitch nice call, I had copied that code from the web and didn't notice it.